# Partitions and refinement—terminology

Tags: terminology, set-partition

Suppose one has a partition $P=\{\{a,b,c\},\{d,e\}\}$ of a set $X=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

Which of these is a *refinement* of $P$:

1. $\{\{\{a,b\},\{c\}\},\{d,e\}\}$; or
2. $\{\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d,e\}\}$?

What (if anything) is the formal term for the other, in respect of $P$?

Is there a term for a "total refinement" of the first example, e.g. $\{\{\{\{a\},\{b\}\},\{c\}\},\{\{d\},\{e\}\}\}$, such that it cannot be "refined" any further?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment?

Comment: Imo this is a good question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Doesn't this terminology fall within set theory?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Was rather hoping you might have helped clarify my misunderstanding...?

Answer (score 0):

A partition $Q$ is a *refinement* of a partition $P$ if every element of $Q$ is a subset of an element of $P$. So for your question 2. is a refinement of $P$.
(I do not understand your notation for 2.)

The partition $\{ \{a\}. \{b\}, \{c\}, \{d\}, \{e\} \}$ is called the *finest* partition.

Incidentally, a slicker notation for a partition is $ab|c|de$ with a simple bar separating elements in the same cell.

Comment: Thank you.  However, I'm actually more interested in the first case given in my question—you have at least helped me to understand that it is not a "refinement" of P, but what is it?  How would one formally describe such a set (and an extremity thereof, as shown)?